# pause for loop till event

Tags: c#, events, for-loop

I'm calling a thread from within a for loop that closes a document. The problem is, the loop continues and tries to open another document before the code in the thread finishes. How can I pause the loop and wait for the document close event. Thanks.

edit

here is my code...

```
    public void OpenFile()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            if (i != 1)
            {
                try
                {
                    uiApp.OpenAndActivateDocument(TargetPath(i));
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                }
            }
            ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback(CloseDoc));
        }
    }

    static void CloseDoc(object stateInfo)
    {
        try
        {
            SendKeys.SendWait("^{F4}");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

I tried adding 'Thread.Sleep(3000)' after CloseDoc, that didn't work. It looks like 'waitone methods in manual/auto reset event classes' would be my best bet. @GAPS can you elaborate? Thank you!

Comment: What's the point of using threads if you are going to freeze the calling thread?

Comment: topofsteel i added code to answer you

Comment: You can use this meaningless code `for(....){ var task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => Method1()); task.Wait(); }`

Comment: The API does not support closing a document. The thread calls sendkeys("^F4"), one of the work arrounds, and it only works in a separate thread for some reason. I'll post my code when I get home. I thought about waiting, but I don't know if it will take the same amount it time each time. So that's why I was tying to have the close document event continue the loop.

Comment: @L.B I've been experimenting with 'Task.Factory.StartNew...', how would I use that with my code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please elaborate your question...
for time being to answer your question I will suggest you to use `waitone` methods in `manual/auto reset event classes`. you can notify your waiting thread that your document is closed and then you can proceed.

[AutoReset](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.autoresetevent.aspx)

[ManualReset](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.manualresetevent.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

If you have to wait for each thread finishes, you may call all code in one thread. If you want to avoid freezing the UI - create a method:

```
public void DoWork()
{
   foreach(/*  your code here*/)
   {
      // do work with documents
   }
}
```

and run it in on non-ui thread.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your code, I can't answer for your specific case, but look into the lock keyword and/or wait handles

See this link:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173179.aspx

Answer (score 0):

try with this code

```
 private object verrou = new object();

 for(int i = 0; i < index; i++)
 {
       lock (verrou )
        {
            // Access thread-sensitive resources.
        }
 }
```